# Calling a C++ CUDA device function from a Python kernel

Tags: python, cuda, cython, numba, pycuda

I'm working on a project that involves creating CUDA kernels in Python. Numba works quite well (what these guys have accomplished is quite incredible), and so does PyCUDA.

My problem is that I want to call a C device function from my Python generated kernel. I couldn't find a way to accomplish this. Numba can call CFFI modules but only in CPU code. In PyCUDA I can add my C device functions to the SourceModule, but I couldn't figure out how to include functions that already exist in another library.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: are you asking about pycuda or numba pro?

Comment: An answer for either would be excellent.

Comment: I ended up using PyCUDA and calling templated C++ functions by including them. This circumvented the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I am aware, this isn't possible in either language. Neither exposes the necessary toolchain controls for separate compilation or APIs to do runtime linking of device code.